# Do vacuum solutions of Einstein's field equation violate Mach principle?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, inertial-frames, vacuum, machs-principle

The Schwarzschild metric is mainly used to define the gravitational field on exterior region of an isolated, spherically symmetric body, but isolated bodies, according to [Mach's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle), are meaningless and don't have any gravitational effect.

So does that mean the Schwarzschild metric violates Mach's principle?

Comment: What do you mean by "Mach's principle"? There are many different but related statements in the context of general relativity that get called that. Why do you think your particular interpretation of Mach's principle should hold?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Why do you think the OP’s question is limited to “his interpretation” of the Mach’s principle? Perhaps the OP would appreciate an answer clarifying which interpretations contradict the Schwarzschild solution and which don’t. Sadly some members here assume that a person asking a question must be an expert on the subject or otherwise must be downvoted. If only experts were allowed to ask questions here, this site would cease to exist. As a perceived expert, how many questions did you personally ask in the past 4 years? - None. The downvote as unjustified +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does that mean the Schwarzschild metric violates Mach's principle?

The Mach’s principle is false. Inertial forces are consequence of non-inertial trajectories, i.e. non-straight lines in four-dimensional spacetime.

An excellent and comprehensive discussion of Mach's principle in context of General Relativity you can find in Briane Greene's book “The Fabric of Cosmos” in Chapter 2 and 3. By the way, this book should be on everyone's shelf who is interested in physics. A quick glimpse into it is possible here:

https://rcsstewa.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/The-Fabric-of-the-Cosmos-Space-Time-and-the-Texture-of-Reality-by-Brian-Greene-z-lib.org_.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The physical content of Mach's principle is that local and global ways of determining a non-rotating frame will agree. This may be tested by experiments like Foucault's pendulum.

The Schwarzschild metric is counterfactual in that it assumes an empty universe. We assume it's a good approximation when the density in the neighborhood is relatively low, but one must never forget that all physical models are approximate.

To apply the physical interpretation of Mach's principle to a counterfactual situation isn't physics any more: no experiment is possible. In particular, in an empty universe, there is no global frame to compare to your local frame.